# "Reports -> custom report" menu option in SQL server 2005 management studio express is missing. why?

Tags: sql-server-2005, report

I have installed:

- MS SQL Server 2005 9.00.4035.00 SP3 Express Edition
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express   9.00.2047.00
- Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.0.6001.18000 (longhorn_rtm.080118-1840)
- Microsoft MSXML 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
- Microsoft Internet Explorer  7.0.6001.18000
- Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0.50727.3074
- Operating System 6.0.6001 (windows vista)

I installed [SQL Server Performance Dashboard.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1d3a4a0d-7e0c-4730-8204-e419218c1efc&displaylang=en) And I'm trying to follow the steps here: [Installing SQL Server 2005 Performance Dashboard Reports](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1553)

This step is included: "Right click on any node in the Object Explorer and click on Custom Reports..."

[image: custom report menu]

But in my contextual menu there is no "reports" option, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick guess: patch your client tools (Management Studio) to SP3/4035 too.

You have the SP1 RTM tools (build 2047) and [custom reports are for SP2 onwards](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/custom-reports-in-management-studio,-using-the-performance-dashboard/)

It's generally best to keep client and server (even express) patched to the same level.